# Is it allowed to call non-static methods with call_user_func?

Tags: php, oop

When I use `call_user_func` on a non-static method in PHP 5.2 I get a Strict Warning:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method User::register() cannot be called statically
```

But on PHP 5.3.1 I don't get this warning. Is this a bug in PHP 5.3.1 or is the warning removed?

Comment: You'll get the same warning on PHP5.3. Looks like your php5.3 and php5.2 configuration are different. Have a look at `error_reporting`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is perfectly OK -- but note that you have to pass an object that's an instance of your class, to indicate on which object the non-static method shall be called :

```
class MyClass {
    public function hello() {
        echo "Hello, World!";
    }
}

$a = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($a, 'hello'));
```

You should not use something like this :

```
call_user_func('MyClass::hello');
```

Which will give you the following warning :

```
Strict standards: `call_user_func()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
non-static method `MyClass::hello()` should not be called statically
```

*(This would work perfectly fine if the method was declared as static... but it's not, here)*

For more informations, you can take a look at the [**callback**][1] section of the manual, which states, amongst other things *(quoting)* :

> A method of an instantiated object is
> passed as an array containing an
> object at index 0 and the method name
> at index 1.

If you get a strict error with an old version of PHP (e.g. 5.2), it's probably a matter of configuration -- I'm thinking about the [**`error_reporting`**][2] directive.

Note that `E_ALL` includes `E_STRICT` **from PHP 5.4.0** *([quoting](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php))* :

Comment: E_STRICT is supposed to be included in E_ALL in PHP 5.3 I think. Btw thank you, I instantiated the object and then it works just fine.

Comment: OK about instanciating the object :-) ;;; I don't think E_STRICT is included in E_ALL, even in PHP 5.3 -- I suppose it would be said so in the manual ;-)

Comment: `E_ALL` does include `E_STRICT` in 5.5 for sure.

Comment: Note that if the method is in the same class you can use `call_user_func(array($this, 'hello'));` such as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288105/php-call-a-instance-method-with-call-user-func-within-the-same-class?rq=1)

Comment: one-liner `call_user_func( [ ( new MyClass() ), 'hello' ] );`