# PHP Call a instance method with call_user_func within the same class

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `call_user_func` to call a method from another method of the same object, e.g.

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo('bar');
    }
    public function foo($method)
    {
        return call_user_func(array($this, $method), 'Hello World');
    }

    public function bar($message)
    {
        echo $message;
    }
}
```

`new MyClass;` Should return 'Hello World'...

Does anyone know the correct way to achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks about right. What doesn't work?

Comment: [Return](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) has defined meaning in PHP and if you are refering to something else, you should clarify that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The code you posted should work just fine. An alternative would be to use ["variable functions"](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) like this:

```
public function foo($method)
{
     //safety first - you might not need this if the $method
     //parameter is tightly controlled....
     if (method_exists($this, $method))
     {
         return $this->$method('Hello World');
     }
     else
     {
         //oh dear - handle this situation in whatever way
         //is appropriate
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: this is also faster than using `call_user_func` though I've seen many frown upon doing it this way... I am not one of those :-)

Comment: this is one of those 'with great power comes great responsibility' idioms...use it for good, not evil :)

Comment: I would slightly frown upon this because it throws a fatal error if the method doesn't exist, but it's probably safe to assume that check is done elsewhere

Comment: @pekka: well for me this is **always** wrapped in check for `method_exists($obj, $method)` or `is_callable` depending on the usage.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that approach :)

Answer (score 22):

This works for me:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo('bar');
    }
    public function foo($method)
    {
        return call_user_func(array($this, $method), 'Hello World');
    }

    public function bar($message)
    {
        echo $message;
    }
}

$mc = new MyClass();
?>
```

This gets printed out:

```
wraith:Downloads mwilliamson$ php userfunc_test.php 
    Hello World
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it another go, I must of had an error when I originally tried it!

Comment: Should be the best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> new MyClass; Should return 'Hello World'...

A constructor does not return anything.

Comment: I think "return" is meant in a very loose sense here (read: he means the `echo`). Still, you're right

Comment: @Pekka and whoever agreed with you. If the OP meant `return` to mean `echo`, then why is the OP asking the question? The code **does** `echo` when the ctor is invoked.

Comment: @Gordon the OP is 1) returning the results of a function that doesn't return anything, and 2) not attempting to return anything in the constructor. To me, that is overwhelming evidence that he didn't really mean "return" :)

Comment: @gordon: I agreed with Pekka. And while your interpretation is valid formt he point you mention i would say that Pekka's is as well since the OP doesnt even attempt a `return $this->foo('bar')` in his constructor :-)

Comment: @Pekka `bar` does not return anything, but that doesnt mean that other methods might not return something. `foo` is just invoking arbitrary methods so it's reasonable to have a return there.

Comment: @prodigitalson sure, but then why is the OP asking the question, because the class as it stands already does `echo` when the ctor is called.