# php class function as parameter with $this->

Tags: php, web-services, class

I have a webservice class with a number of private functions. I have a main function which decides which function to call according to the first parameter of the web service call.

```
$actions = [
        "CHECK_LOGIN"     => "checkLogin" 
    ,   "CHECK_FB"        => "checkFB"  
    ,   "GET_DETAILS"     => "getDetails" 
    ,   "SAVE_DETAILS"    => "saveDetails" 
    ,   "CHANGE_PWD"      => "saveDetails" 
    ,   "SEND_ECODE"      => "sendEmailCode"
]
```

So, its easy to find which function to call according to the parameter passed:

```
if (!array_key_exists($action, $actions))
  $rep = ["status" => STATUS_ERROR, "errMsg" => "Action '$action' unknown"];
else {
   $method = $actions[$action];
   $rep = $method($req);
}
```

My problem is that I can't call "$method" what ever it is (e.g. "checkFB"), I need to call $this->method (i.e. "$this->checkFB")
How do I put the $this-> in front of the function name found in the $actions array??

Comment: I was trying to call "$this->method", but what I needed was "$this->$method" !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Call a instance method with call\_user\_func within the same class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288105/php-call-a-instance-method-with-call-user-func-within-the-same-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if (!array_key_exists($action, $actions))
  $rep = ["status" => STATUS_ERROR, "errMsg" => "Action '$action' unknown"];
else {
   $method = $actions[$action];
   $rep = $this->$method($req);
}
```